# Is a $PL$-manifold necessarily a pure simplicial complex?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, simplicial-complex

A text I am reading treats $PL$-manifolds as if they were pure simplicial complexes. However it defines $n$-dimensional $PL$-manifold as $n$-dimensional simplicial complex with the property that link of every vertex is a piecewise linear sphere $S^{n-1}$. How does this definition guarantee that the simplicial complex must be pure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that by "pure" in this context you mean that every simplex is a face of some $n$-simplex, in which case this follows from an algebraic topology calculation.

First, the condition on links implies that $X$ is an $n$-manifold in the topological sense.

In a simplicial complex $X$, if $\sigma \subset X$ is a simplex of dimension $m$, and if $\sigma$ is not a face of any higher dimensional simplex of $X$, then for any $x \in \text{interior}(\sigma)$ and any integer $i \ge 0$, the [relative homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_homology) of $X$ relative to its subspace $X-x$ is given by:
$$H_i(X,X-x) \approx \begin{cases}
0 & \quad\text{if $i \ne m$} \\
\mathbb Z &\quad\text{if $i=m$}
\end{cases}
$$
But if $X$ is an $n$-manifold, then $H_n(X,X-x) \approx \mathbb Z$.

Comment: By $H_i(X, X-x)$ you mean the $i$-th homology group of the space $X-x$, relative to the space $X$?

Comment: No, it's the other way around: the $i$-th homology group of the space $X$ relative to its subspace $X-x$.